# Need mirror css shadow

Tags: html, css

```
.hr-line {
margin: -30px auto 10px;
padding: 0;
height: 50px;
border: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid;
box-shadow: 0 20px 20px -20px;
width: 95%;
}
```

this is this line (highlighted in the screenshot)

[image: 1]

you need to make the shadow up, as in the photo, just the opposite.
Please help, im newbie :DDDD

Comment: `box-shadow: 0 -20px 20px -20px;`

Comment: use translator ... 1 answer give you what you need

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide HTML code so we can actually improve on your code and help, otherwise it is useless that you even ask for help. https://stackoverflow.com/tour https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are other options, but makes sense to rotate it 180 degrees.

```css
.hr-line {
  margin: 30px auto -30px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px -20px;
  width: 95%;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
text before
<div class="hr-line"></div>
text after, play with the margin: 30px auto -30px;
```

Comment: It is kinda patchy. Better would have been change the values.

Comment: @ITgoldman https://imgur.com/a/3G28qwc how to fix?